# Form gets submitted even if JavaScript fun returns false

Tags: javascript, jsp, submit

Pls check code .html form gets submitted even if javascript returns false.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1"   method="post" action="sub.jsp" onsubmit="return getValue()">
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"   onkeyup="return getValue()" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function getValue()
      {
        var userName=document.getElementById("userName");
            document.getElementById("userNamemsg").innerHTML="";
              if(userName.value=="")
              {
             var mdiv=document.getElementById("userNamemsg");
                  mdiv.innerHTML="Error:Required Fields cannot be blank!";
                  form.userName.focus();
                  return false;
               }
              return true;   
     }
```

Comment: Please update your code sample: (1) the script element isn't closed, (2) I can't find element userNamemsg (3) use userName.focus() instead of form.userName.focus();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) try changing line **`form.userName.focus();`** to **`document.form1.userName.focus();`**

OR

2) try submitting from function itself:

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="getValue()" />

<script type="text/javascript" >
function getValue()
  {
        var userName=document.getElementById("userName");
        document.getElementById("userNamemsg").innerHTML="";
          if(userName.value=="")
          {
              var mdiv=document.getElementById("userNamemsg");
              mdiv.innerHTML="Error:Required Fields cannot be blank!";
              document.form1.userName.focus();//I think this is the problem
              return false;
           }
          document.form1.submit();
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are errors in your JavaScript code that happen prior to your return statements.  Fix those errors and your code should work.

Comment: +1 unspecific answer but it's true: in a function like onsubmit or onclick, if your JavaScript errors out, the form will be submitted or link followed anyway. If you haven't turned on the error box on script errors, it can be unclear what has happened.

Answer (score -1):

alternatively, you make the click handler on the submit button to return false.